# making GET requests with params give different result than encoded url

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to get data from an api using python GET requests.

The following works:

```py
import requests

response = requests.get('http://hilltop.gw.govt.nz/Data.hts?Service=Hilltop&Request=GetData&Site=Korokoro%20Stream%20at%20Mill%20Weir&Measurement=Stage&From=2018-01-01%2000:00:00&To=2018-01-02%2000:00:00&interval=undefined')

response.content.decode('utf-8')

# response
'<?xml version="1.0" ?>\n<Hilltop>\n<Agency>GWRC</Agency>\n<Measurement SiteName="Korokoro Stream at Mill Weir">\n<DataSource Name="Water Level" NumItems="1">\n<TSType>StdSeries</TSType>\n<DataType>SimpleTimeSeries</DataType>\n<Interpolation>Instant</Interpolation>\n<ItemInfo ItemNumber="1">\n<ItemName>Stage</ItemName><ItemFormat>F</ItemFormat><Units>mm</Units><Format>####</Format>\n</ItemInfo>\n</DataSource>\n<Data DateFormat="Calendar" NumItems="1">\n<E><T>2018-01-01T00:00:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T00:05:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T00:10:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T00:15:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T00:20:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T00:25:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T00:30:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T00:35:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T00:40:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T00:45:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T00:50:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T00:55:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T01:00:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T01:05:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T01:10:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T01:15:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T01:20:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T01:25:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T01:30:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T01:35:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T01:40:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T01:45:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T01:50:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T01:55:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T02:00:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T02:05:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T02:10:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T02:15:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T02:20:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T02:25:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T02:30:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T02:35:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T02:40:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T02:45:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T02:50:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T02:55:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T03:00:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T03:05:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T03:10:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T03:15:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T03:20:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T03:25:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T03:30:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T03:35:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T03:40:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T03:45:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T03:50:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T03:55:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T04:00:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T04:05:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T04:10:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T04:15:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T04:20:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T04:25:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T04:30:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T04:35:00</T><I1>407</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T04:40:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T04:45:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T04:50:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T04:55:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T05:00:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T05:05:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T05:10:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T05:15:00</T><I1>407</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T05:20:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T05:25:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T05:30:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T05:35:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T05:40:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T05:45:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T05:50:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T05:55:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T06:00:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T06:05:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T06:10:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T06:15:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T06:20:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T06:25:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T06:30:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T06:35:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T06:40:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T06:45:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T06:50:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T06:55:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T07:00:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T07:05:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T07:10:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T07:15:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T07:20:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T07:25:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T07:30:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T07:35:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T07:40:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T07:45:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T07:50:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T07:55:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T08:00:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T08:05:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T08:10:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T08:15:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T08:20:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T08:25:00</T><I1>407</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T08:30:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T08:35:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T08:40:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T08:45:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T08:50:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T08:55:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T09:00:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T09:05:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T09:10:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T09:15:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T09:20:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T09:25:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T09:30:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T09:35:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T09:40:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T09:45:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T09:50:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T09:55:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T10:00:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T10:05:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T10:10:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T10:15:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T10:20:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T10:25:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T10:30:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T10:35:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T10:40:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T10:45:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T10:50:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T10:55:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T11:00:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T11:05:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T11:10:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T11:15:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T11:20:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T11:25:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T11:30:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T11:35:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T11:40:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T11:45:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T11:50:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T11:55:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T12:00:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T12:05:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T12:10:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T12:15:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T12:20:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T12:25:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T12:30:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T12:35:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T12:40:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T12:45:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T12:50:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T12:55:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T13:00:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T13:05:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T13:10:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T13:15:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T13:20:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T13:25:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T13:30:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T13:35:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T13:40:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T13:45:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T13:50:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T13:55:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T14:00:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T14:05:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T14:10:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T14:15:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T14:20:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T14:25:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T14:30:00</T><I1>406</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T14:35:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T14:40:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T14:45:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T14:50:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T14:55:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T15:00:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T15:05:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T15:10:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T15:15:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T15:20:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T15:25:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T15:30:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T15:35:00</T><I1>405</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T15:40:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T15:45:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T15:50:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T15:55:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T16:00:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T16:05:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T16:10:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T16:15:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T16:20:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T16:25:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T16:30:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T16:35:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T16:40:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T16:45:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T16:50:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T16:55:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T17:00:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T17:05:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T17:10:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T17:15:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T17:20:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T17:25:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T17:30:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T17:35:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T17:40:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T17:45:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T17:50:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T17:55:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T18:00:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T18:05:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T18:10:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T18:15:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T18:20:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T18:25:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T18:30:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T18:35:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T18:40:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T18:45:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T18:50:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T18:55:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T19:00:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T19:05:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T19:10:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T19:15:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T19:20:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T19:25:00</T><I1>402</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T19:30:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T19:35:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T19:40:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T19:45:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T19:50:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T19:55:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T20:00:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T20:05:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T20:10:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T20:15:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T20:20:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T20:25:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T20:30:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T20:35:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T20:40:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T20:45:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T20:50:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T20:55:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T21:00:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T21:05:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T21:10:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T21:15:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T21:20:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T21:25:00</T><I1>402</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T21:30:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T21:35:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T21:40:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T21:45:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T21:50:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T21:55:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T22:00:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T22:05:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T22:10:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T22:15:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T22:20:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T22:25:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T22:30:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T22:35:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T22:40:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T22:45:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T22:50:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T22:55:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T23:00:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T23:05:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T23:10:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T23:15:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T23:20:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T23:25:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T23:30:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T23:35:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T23:40:00</T><I1>404</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T23:45:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T23:50:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-01T23:55:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n<E><T>2018-01-02T00:00:00</T><I1>403</I1></E>\n</Data>\n</Measurement>\n</Hilltop>\n'
```

However, when I take out the query params and put it in the `params` argument of the get request, the server returns no data:

```py
import requests

params = (
    ('Service', 'Hilltop'),
    ('Request', 'GetData'),
    ('Site', 'Korokoro Stream at Mill Weir'),
    ('Measurement', 'Stage'),
    ('From', '2018-01-01 00:00:00'),
    ('To', '2018-01-02 00:00:00'),
    ('interval', 'undefined'),
)

response = requests.get('http://hilltop.gw.govt.nz/Data.hts', params=params)

response.content.decode('utf-8')

# response
'<HilltopServer><Error>No data for site Korokoro+Stream+at+Mill+Weir</Error></HilltopServer>'
```

As far as I know, if the params are passed in the argument, the params will get encoded in the query string and a GET request will invoke using that query string, so the 2 above methods should give the same results.

I wonder if this has something to do with the server, or my understanding is incorrect?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at response.url you can see the problem -- the spaces in the site name are being converted to plus signs.

`http://hilltop.gw.govt.nz/Data.hts?Service=Hilltop&Request=GetData&Site=Korokoro+Stream+at+Mill+Weir&Measurement=Stage&From=2018-01-01+00%3A00%3A00&To=2018-01-02+00%3A00%3A00&interval=undefined`

Luckily there is a way to url encode the params:

```
import requests
import urllib

params = (
    ('Service', 'Hilltop'),
    ('Request', 'GetData'),
    ('Site', 'Korokoro Stream at Mill Weir'),
    ('Measurement', 'Stage'),
    ('From', '2018-01-01 00:00:00'),
    ('To', '2018-01-02 00:00:00'),
    ('interval', 'undefined'),
)
# Encode params
params = urllib.parse.urlencode(params, quote_via=urllib.parse.quote)

response = requests.get('http://hilltop.gw.govt.nz/Data.hts', params=params)

response.content.decode('utf-8')
```